# datetime-local is showing the data type template on Html.TextBox input box rather than DateTime value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

How can I display the preset value of model rather than showing the datetime template on input box?

Current view on Edit page for input with type = datetime-local

[image]

The code for TextBox right now

```
@Html.TextBox("EffectiveDate", (DateTime)ViewBag.EffectiveDate, new {  @type="datetime-local", @class="form-control"})
```

I want the text box to display the value of ViewBag.EffectiveDate rather than "dd/mm/yyyy --:-- --"

Ideally, the text box should be like this but also gives option for user to edit the date

[image]

The code on ViewBag

```
var pacEffectiveDate = await _context.LocationPac.Where(l => l.LocationID == id).Select(l => l.EffectiveDate).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
ViewData["EffectiveDate"] = pacEffectiveDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing -local from **@type="datetime-local"** and use **@type="datetime"**.
Also assign effective date in ViewData as **DateTime** instead of **string**.

Comment: Changing to @type = "datetime" doesnt work on mine. The datepicker is not available.

Answer (score 0):

So you can do it like this if you don't have a problem with using the **input tag.**

```
<input id="meeting-time" max="2018-06-14T00:00" min="2018-06-07T00:00" name="meeting-time" type="datetime-local" value="2018-06-12T19:30:30" />
```

This will be the result:

[image]

And it also allows you to change the date:

[image]

For more information visit the page by [clicking here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local):